# Ionic Build Error

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, build

Boa noite.
Tenho um pequeno projeto feito com Ionic 1 que está dando o seguinte erro quando rodo o comando ionic build android:

C:\GrantSoft\apps\IdeiasDePresentes\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-eu\values-eu.xml: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1

:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.

  > C:\GrantSoft\apps\IdeiasDePresentes\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-eu\values-eu.xml: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1
- Try:

Run with

--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.835 secs

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.

  > C:\GrantSoft\apps\IdeiasDePresentes\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-eu\values-eu.xml: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Alguem já passou por isso?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi reinstalando tudo. 
Jdk1.7.0_79
Build Tools 23.0.2